# How To Fire An Event /Function From A Code Behind When I Type 6Th Digit In A Textbox?

Tags: c#, asp.net

How To Fire An Event /Function From A Code Behind When I Type 6Th Digit In A Textbox ?

My uestion is very simple
I am a programmer of C#
how to fire an event /function from a code behind when i type 6th digit in a textbox ??

Comment: Your question is very simple but the solution is less so. What have you tried so far ? Do you know how to fire Ajax requests in jquery ?

Comment: no kindly help actual i have a pincode text box as pin code is of 6 digit  so when user enters the 6th  digit of the pin code i want to fire a event which will populate its corrosponding district from code behind. As i want to use code behind code so i cant use javascript for this . any possible solution ?

Answer (score 1):

After reading your requirements from the comments in the question, I suggest you to use Web Service or Page method for your current problem.

Your problem can be solved in the following way:

1. Use jQuery in your project.
2. Write a javascript "onchange" function for your textbox.
3. Calculate length of the text in textbox in this javascript function.
4. When the length equals "6" then fire a web service request via jQuery.
5. The web-service shall return data that you need to capture in your javascript.
6. Display the data.

A sample code is as below:

Javascript function for calculating length:

```
      function caculateTextboxLenth() {
            if (document.getElementById("<Textbox Id>").length == 6) {
                var text = document.getElementById("<Textbox Id>").text;
                CallWebService("/getDistrictData",text);
            }
            return false;
        }
```

Javascript function for calling web page method:

```
function CallWebService(WebServiceURL,text) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        cache: false,
        url: WebServiceURL + "&pincode=" text + "&dt=" + new Date().getTime(), //This will append ?dt={timestamp} to the URL to prevent caching,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: ShowData,
        error: error
    });
}
```

Your C# page method shall be like the following in your code behind file.

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
    public static string getDistrict()
    {
        int pincode = Convert.ToInt32(HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString["pincode"].ToString().Trim());
        string district = "";
        //code to fetch district
        return district;
    }
```

P.S: Do check for SQL injections.

Comment: I cant call a webservice i just want to call a codebehind method
can i call a code behind method through javascript?\

Comment: The example he's given is a Page Method, which *is* in the page code behind, albeit as a static member so it cannot access any controls on the page instance itself. This is a good solution.

Comment: I dont want to use webservice!!
Dear sh1rts , You are absolutely correct ontextchange fires only when we leave the focus but i need to fire the code behind on 6th digit entered. this can be only doe if can able to call sserver side method from javascript which fires on onchange . Is it possible to call server side method from javascript ?

Comment: I really don't know why you're so opposed to using a Page Method - this is a web service INSIDE THE PAGE ITSELF. Why is this not an option ? Your only other option is to call the generated __doPostBack client-side method, which posts the page. Good luck with that.

Comment: You *cannot* otherwise "call a server side method" of a webforms page from JavaScript. You have to use either a web service or page method.

Answer (score 0):

attach two events to textbox
1)Javascript onchange
2)c# OnTextChanged

check validations for characters in onchange and if true then "return true;"
which will fire OnTextChanged event on server side.

Also do no forget to put "AutoPostBack" property of textbox to true.

Comment: This solution was there in my mind as second option. If any other or direct solution can be provided  ??

Comment: do not use on change.use ontextchanged directly. above solution will save u unwanted postbacks

Comment: heyThanks for the help.
But the problem which i had in the above your code is that on entering the 6th digit nothing is firing i need to either keep the focus out of the textbox or enter button
But i want as soon as i press enter the 6th digit the code behind event will be fired

Comment: This example does not address his needs, which is for the event to fire when the 6th digit is typed. TextChanged is fired when focus leaves the control.

Comment: Dear  sh1rts , You are absolutely correct ontextchange fires only when we leave the focus but i need to fire the code behind on 6th digit entered. this can be only doe if can able to call sserver side method from javascript which fires on onchange . Is it possible to call server side method from javascript ?

Answer (score 0):

My solution may not be perfect but put your `texbox` in `UpdatePanel` double click it to create an event, now use `int.Parse` to see that if entered input is integer or not and use `txtbx.Text.Length` to see if you got the sixth digit or not.

it should be something like this

```
if(txtbx.Text.Trim().Length > 0 && int.Parse(txtbx.Text.Trim(), out intoutput))
{
    if(txtbx.Text.Trim().Length = 6 )
    {
    // your code here
    }
}
```